# Use an appropriate test to determine if the series converges or diverges: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n+1}{2n^2+3n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I was wondering how to go about this problem--which test could I use and how would I go about solving this problem? Thanks so much in advance.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{2n+1}{2n^2+3n-1}$$

Comment: Try the integral test.

Comment: Limit comparison works nicely as well.

Comment: Yeah... actually, limit comparison probably is the way to go.  Use the harmonic series.

Answer (score 2):

### Hint:

$$\frac{2n+1}{2n^2+3n-1}>\frac{2n+1}{2n^2+3n}=\frac1n-\frac{2}{2n^3+3n^2}$$

Comment: Clean and concise! And a(h!) minute sooner than me... Nice answer!

Comment: @mathbeing Thank you!  (though I don't get the 'h!')

Comment: That (the 'ah!', which I tried to integrate with the article 'a') was meant to be a frustration-onomatopoeia. Sorry if it really makes no sense, I am still learning English and I find these kind of expressions particularly hard to understand sometimes.

Comment: Haha, oh, I get it now.  Sorry if I was, at least indirectly, frustrating XD

Comment: Oh, no worries!! =) I think I didn't wrote what I meant again so let me do the little change of variables $frustration\leftarrow \frac{1+\varepsilon}{2}amusement+\frac{1-\varepsilon}{2}frustration$. ;)

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{2n+1}{2n^2+3n-1}>\frac{2n+1}{2n^2+3n+1}=\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: Oh nice.  I just didn't try to bother with factoring because of the first coefficient, but that turned out good, didn't it?